# Positioning of tikz nodes in one line

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I position the text above the time line in same height, i. e. so that they appear as being on the same line? I think the "p" is higher than the "E".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \draw[->,>=] (-1,0) -- (9,0);
    \draw[shift={(0,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$1$};
    \draw[shift={(0,0.8)}] node {p};
    \draw[shift={(4,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$2$};
    \draw[shift={(4,0.8)}] node {E};
    \draw[shift={(8,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$3$};
    \draw[shift={(8,0.8)}] node {J};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: have a look at the answer below please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Applying `anchor=base` to the `tikzpicture` will align the three items at the baseline:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1, anchor=base]
    \draw[->,>=] (-1,0) -- (9,0);
    \draw[shift={(0,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) 
        node[below] {$1$};
    \draw[shift={(0,0.8)}] node {p};
    \draw[shift={(4,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$2$};
    \draw[shift={(4,0.8)}] node {E};
    \draw[shift={(8,0)}] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) node[below] {$3$};
    \draw[shift={(8,0.8)}] node {J};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (10,0);
        \foreach \x/\y/\z in {1/1/p,5/5/E,9/9/J,}{
            \draw[line width=1pt] (\x,-2mm)
            node[below](\x){\strut\y} -- 
            (\x,2mm)node[above=0.5cm]{\z};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

baseline check seems ok

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (10,0);
        \foreach \x/\y/\z in {1/1/p,1.2/1.2/E,1.4/1.4/J,}{
            \draw[line width=1pt] (\x,-2mm)
            node[below](\x){\strut\y} -- 
            (\x,2mm)node[above=0.5cm]{\z};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]